# Compare ArrayList<Object> with List<String>, then perform some calculations and printing out the results

Tags: java, list

I have the following `List<Client>` where names are repeated and are not in order together with a duration in seconds:

1. Name 1 , 100
2. Name 2 , 15
3. Name 3 , 45
4. Name 1 , 30
5. Name 3 , 12
6. Name 2 , 22

This list is read in from a CSV and names are always changing.

I am required to total the duration of each name and print it out in the following way:

- Name 1 , Total Duration : 130
- Name 2 , Total Duration : 37
- Name 3 , Total Duration : 57

This list has over 1000 entries.

Please help as I can't wrap my head around this.

I have extracted a `List<String>` from the `List<Client>` removing duplicates. Leaving me with the following:

- Name 1
- Name 2
- Name 3

However, I am lost after this.

Comment: I think you can just make a loop over the lust and do a switch case but I didnt see that the list is over 1k entries and full of seperate names

Comment: Maybe you could create another list where all the duplicates are removed then you check each item of the non duplicate list with the original list and if the names match, you somehow add up the durations

Comment: You should use a map as your result data structure rather than a list. Iterate over your list, split at comma, use the name as key and the duration as value. Before inserting into the map check if the key already exists, if yes update the value if not insert.

Comment: @Rid00 does my answer work for you?

Comment: Does it have to be done in Java? Awk was made for these types of tasks. `awk -F',' '{x[$1]+=$2}END{for(i in x){print i", Total Duration : "x[i]}}'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a map as your result data structure rather than a list. Iterate over your list, split at comma, use the name as key and the duration as value. Before inserting into the map check if the key already exists, if yes update the value if not insert it. Here ist a simple example to get you started:

Assuming you have a csv file which looks something like:

```
John, 100
Sarah, 15
Alex, 45
John, 30
Sarah, 12
Alex, 22
```

code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        //path to your file, eg. C:\\Users\\Rid00\\Documents\\myfile.csv
        String pathToFile = "path to file";
        List<String> fileContent = readCsvFile(pathToFile);
        Map<String,Integer> durationPerName = getTotalDurations(fileContent);

        //do whatever with your result, for example print it to console
        for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry : durationPerName.entrySet()){
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    public static List<String> readCsvFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        //read all lines of csv file to a list
        Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
        List<String> allLines = Files.readAllLines(path);
        return allLines;
    }

    public static Map<String,Integer> getTotalDurations(List<String> linesFromFile){
        Map<String,Integer> result = new HashMap<>();
        for(String line : linesFromFile){
            //split at comma and remove extra spaces before and/or after the delimiter
            String[] splited = line.split("\\s*,\\s*");
            String name = splited[0];
            int duration = Integer.parseInt(splited[1]);

            //check if map doesn't contains key, if no insert it
            if(!result.containsKey(name)){
                result.put(name, duration);
            }
            //else if map already contains key, get the value and add the current duration to it
            else{
                result.put(name, result.get(name) + duration);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort. I accept your solution as this is the one I understand. Will give Java streams a go in the near future.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Java streams for this, like so ('rl' will be the result list containg your merged entries. 'l' is the source list):

```
List<Entry> rl = new ArrayList<>(
         l.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                 Entry::getName,
                 e -> e,
                 Entry::merge
         )).values()
);
```

or if you want a sorted result:

```
List<Entry> rl = l.stream()
                  .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                          Entry::getName,
                          e -> e,
                          Entry::merge
                  ))
                  .values()
                  .stream()
                  .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Entry::getName))
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I'm using the following data structure (replace it with yours):

```
public static class Entry {
    public String name;
    public long duration;

    public Entry(String name, long duration) {
        this.name = name;
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public long getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name: " + name + ", Total Duration: " + duration;
    }

    public static Entry merge(Entry e1, Entry e2) {
        return new Entry(e1.getName(), e1.getDuration() + e2.getDuration());
    }
}
```

Comment: _if the only tool you have is a hammer_ [Law_of_the_instrument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument)

Comment: @Eritrean it could be solved more elegantly, then creating a Map and streaming the data into a list, but really doesn't matter that much

Comment: @IntoVoid thank you so much for this. I have not yet dealt with streams as I am fairly new to Java. I will give this a try this weekend and report back to you.

Comment: @Eritrean, I will try this as well. So far, with my limited knowledge of java, I do understand your solution. I will give both solutions a shot. Thank you